# Issue in my query to filter for only roads and highways using osmosis/osmfilter in my OSM file?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, graph, osmosis, osmfilter

I wnat to extract all the road types and speed limits from the OSM file for the US.  I started with a small subset (Delaware OSM), and I ran the following query to try to get rid of unnecessary information using the osmosis/osmfilter command.

bin/osmosis --read-xml delaware.osm --tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node --write-xml delaware_highways.osm

This is removing too much information.  I used the OSMNX Python library, which has a function called osmnx.nearest_edges.  You give it a latitude, longitude) point, and it will return the nearest edge of the graph based on that point.  Out of 500 (latitude, longitude) points I test to find the nearest edge, 35 road types are missing on the graph output of this query.
What am i doing wrong in my query to filter for only roads and highways using osmosis/osmfilter in my OSM file?

Comment: So what are the attributes of the missing roads that you have found?

Comment: I also use `route='road'` (which can be found with a null `highway`) and filter out some of the `highway` sub-type (like raceway, pedestrian paths, steps, bike path etc)

Comment: usually they tend to be service road but not always.